# Number of subarrays within a sum range

Tags: python, performance, number-theory

**Question**
Given an array of non negative integers A, and a range (B, C),
find the number of continuous subsequences in the array which have sum S in the range [B, C] or B <= S <= C

Continuous subsequence is defined as all the numbers A[i], A[i + 1], .... A[j]
where 0 <= i <= j < size(A)

Example :

A : [10, 5, 1, 0, 2]
(B, C) : (6, 8)

ans = 3
[5, 1], [5, 1, 0], [5, 1, 0, 2] are the only 3 continuous subsequence with their sum in the range [6, 8]

**My Code**

```
def numRange(A, B, C):

    n = len(A)
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(n-1):

        newsum = A[i]

        j = i + 1
        while newsum <= C and j < n:

            if newsum >= B :
                count += 1
            newsum += A[j]
            j += 1
    if A[n-1] >= B and A[n-1] <= C:
        count += 1
    return count
```

**Problem** : Wrong Answer.

1. What are the cases I am missing ?
2. How do I improve the efficiency of this code after rectifying it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy I used was to effectively buffer the results, until I got to the end, then process the remainder of the buffer. This therefore requires at most, two iterations, or O(n) time.

EDIT: Removed calls to `sum()`:

```
def numRange(A, B, C):

    current = []
    current_sum = 0
    count = 0

    for number in A:
        current.append(number)
        current_sum += number
        while current_sum > C:
            current_sum -= current[0]
            current = current[1:]

        if B <= current_sum <= C:
            count += 1
            print current_sum, current

    # Now check the remaining items in current, in case of a trailing sequence:
    # Test with A = [10, 5, 1, 0, 2, 4] to demonstrate the need.
    if not current:
        return count

    current_sum -= current[0]    
    current = current[1:]
    while (B <= current_sum <= C):
        count += 1
        print current_sum, current
        current_sum -= current[0]
        current = current[1:]

    return count


print "Total of %d subarrays" % numRange( [10, 5, 1, 0, 2], 6, 8)
print
print "Total of %d subarrays" % numRange( [10, 5, 1, 0, 2, 4], 6, 8)
```

Output:

```
6 [5, 1]
6 [5, 1, 0]
8 [5, 1, 0, 2]
Total of 3 subarrays

6 [5, 1]
6 [5, 1, 0]
8 [5, 1, 0, 2]
7 [1, 0, 2, 4]
6 [0, 2, 4]
6 [2, 4]
Total of 6 subarrays
```

Comment: Continuously re-summing over the elements of `current` will get expensive as `A` grows.

Comment: Agreed. But that approach can be optimized by storing the sum and adding or subtracting the elements value from it. My goal was to demonstrate a working algorithm.

Comment: Edited to remove calls to `sum`

Comment: got back from vacation to check out the comments on our answers... and while valid points were raised, the shortcut used here makes it fail for sequences which are separated, for instance `[10, 5, 1, 0, 2, 4, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: You're right. And that may require more than a trivial change in the algorithm, if it's to remain efficient.

Comment: This code would fail if the range would be large enough the include subarrays and subarrays of those subarrays. For example: print "Total of %d subarrays" % numRange( [10, 5, 1, 0, 2, 4], 1, 8) would fail. It will not count the subarrays like [1], [2], [4], [0, 1].

Answer (score 1):

Got it to obey

```
def numRange(A, B, C):
    n = len(A)
    sets = []

    for i in range(n):
        sum = 0
        j = i

        while sum < B and j < n:
            sum += A[j]
            j += 1

        while sum >= B and sum <= C and j <= n:
            if sum <= C:
                sets.append(A[i:j])
            if j < n:
                sum += A[j]
            j += 1

    return sets

sets = numRange([10, 5, 1, 0, 2], 6, 8)
print len(sets) # 3
print sets # [[5, 1], [5, 1, 0], [5, 1, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that it's O(n^2), as it effectively tests every possible valid subsequence.

Comment: The code might not have the best time complexity but it works just fine. Thanks @mike.k

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is for the [5, 1, 0, 2] case. You compute the sum which is equal to 8. Then increment j to 5

```
newsum += A[j] # newsum was 6, add A[4] = 2, now 8
j += 1
```

but then the loop is exited as j now equals 5, failing the j < n condition. So the increment of count never happens for this sum. Unfortunately just switching the order of the things in the inner loop isn't sufficient to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my O(n^2) worst case solution. With O(1) extra space. Can anyone give better solution than this in O(n)

```
class Solution:
    def numRange(self, A, B, C):
        count = 0
        end = len(A)-1
        tot = 0
        temp_sum = 0
        temp_array = []
        tot_sum = sum(A[0:len(A)])
        for i in range(len(A)):
            current_sum = 0
            for j in range(i,len(A)):
                current_sum += A[j]
                if(current_sum > C):
                    break
                elif(B <= current_sum <= C):
                    #print current_sum
                    tot += 1
            tot_sum -= A[i]
            if(tot_sum < B):
                break
        return tot
```

Comment: I find this answer neither relevant nor useful.
Since, your query differs from mine, I think you should ask a new question, rather than spoiling this feed.

Comment: it's the answer to your question. And i'm sure @ Moshe's code fails in many situations.